# Selected range identification

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am looking for a best way to uniquely identify/recognize a selected range within Office.js Excel workbook. So far I am using bindings to set a name for a range i.e. `A1:A1`. However, it is not clear how to check when user selects the above range if it is a  part of the above binding in the workbook.
To set the binding i use the below code:

```
 var myBindings = Office.context.document.bindings;
            var myAddress = "Sheet1!A1:A1";
            myBindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(myAddress, Office.BindingType.Matrix, { id: "myBind" }, function (asyncResult) {
                asyncResult.value.getDataAsync(function (asyncResult2) {
                    console.log(asyncResult2.value);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use getIntersectionOrNullObject to detect whether your selection is in namedRanges or not. it can return address of the selectedRange in getIntersectionOrNullObject or it will return null object

Here is the sample code

```
 Excel.run(function (ctx) {

    const selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    var binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItemAt(0);
    var range = binding.getRange();

    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var rangeAddress = "A1:F8"; // replace to binding range address
    // var rangeAddress = range.address;

    var range =
      ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress).getIntersectionOrNullObject(selectedRange);

    range.load('address');

    console.log("test");
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
      console.log("test2");

      console.log(range.address);  
    });
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });
```